# UIWebView keeps trying to load but with no results

Tags: ios

I'm trying to connect to a wikiTravel page using a UIWebView. Here is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://wikitravel.org/en/Beijing"];

NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[wikiWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

If I change Beijing to Cornwall, it works great and shows me all the information. If I change Beijing to Montreal, it loads only the wikitravel logo and two buttons, but it does call `webViewDidFinishLoad`. But with Beijing it just loads and loads and doesn't display anything.

I print to the console whenever a UIWebView method is called, here is the output:

```
2012-06-11 15:11:50.904 ExtraFeatures3[893:307] WEB VIEW DID START LOAD.
2012-06-11 15:11:57.607 ExtraFeatures3[893:307] WEB VIEW FAILED TO LOAD: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x19be10 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://wikitravel.org/en/Beijing, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://wikitravel.org/en/Beijing}
2012-06-11 15:11:57.619 ExtraFeatures3[893:307] WEB VIEW DID START LOAD.
2012-06-11 15:11:59.523 ExtraFeatures3[893:307] WEB VIEW FAILED TO LOAD: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1a3190 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://wikitravel.org/en/Beijing, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://wikitravel.org/en/Beijing}
2012-06-11 15:11:59.534 ExtraFeatures3[893:307] WEB VIEW DID START LOAD.
2012-06-11 15:12:00.875 ExtraFeatures3[893:307] WEB VIEW FAILED TO LOAD: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -999.)" UserInfo=0x1a6e00 {NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://wikitravel.org/en/Beijing, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://wikitravel.org/en/Beijing}
```

And it just keeps going and going and going.... I have no idea what to do with this.

**EDIT**: All my searches have led me to the following workaround, which I have tried and have not gotten to work:

```
-(void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if([error code] == NSURLErrorCancelled)
    {
        return;
    }
```

}

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I would say its a bug in the website, they are adapting the content for mobile browsers and making a mistake somewhere that is causing an infinite redirect. The user agent for UIWebView is different for Mobile Safari this throws out their logic. If I have the time I'll go through their source code, but that is what I think could be happening.

Answer (score 3):

According to this site: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1727260?start=0&tstart=0

This is the work around:

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 NSLog(@"Error %i", error.code);
 if (error.code == NSURLErrorCancelled) return; // this is Error -999
 // error handling for "real" errors here
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had already tried this and it doesn't help. Thanks

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work but no success. Even when I launch that site in iOS safari it crashes.  edit: nevermind this comment. I was able to load it in safari but it was very slow

Comment: Crashes?? When I type the URL straight into iOS safari it works but doesn't show any info about Beijing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead Of trying your url, first try

`NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"];`

are you able to load ?

Comment: Yes it loads with no problems

Comment: Is Beijing, Cornwall and Montreal are parameters ? passing to Url ?

Comment: Yes. if you look at the question above, you can replace Beijing with any city name and it should work.

Comment: ya i tried, it's working, there might be white spaces in your parameter, `trim` your parameter and pass to `url`